# What is the meaning of the term "Accent color"?

Tags: macos, ios

**What's the meaning of the so-called "Accent color" in MacOS and iOS?** One sees it in the system-preferences of MacOS ("Appearance"-section), but it isn't clear to me what's specified there.

Comment: Very simple answer: "it's like window color".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's 'highlight colour' in effect.

[image]
[image]
[image]

It changes the colour of Menu headers & highlights, text highlights, selected file highlight etc

[image]

You can also see it reflected in the Appearance thumbnails as you change it -

[image]  [image]

If you change Accent first, highlight follows it, otherwise you can change highlight afterwards [if you feel the need] to make them contrasting…

[image]

Pre-Ventura, it's in System Preferences > General. In Ventura it's been moved to System Setting > Appearance.

[image]

Comment: @Thinkr In MacOS in the System Preferences, Section "Appearance" it might be named in English, I guess ...

Comment: @Scientology All the options are in that dialog. Light or Dark, the Accent & Highlight colours. There is no Themes support like in Windows or the various Linux DEs. The choice of wallpaper (dynamic or otherwise) will also have an effect on colouring aspects of certain transparent sections of the UI.

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on the question mark in the bottom right corner, you get to the macOS User Guide which tells us:

> - Accent colour
>
>   Choose the colour to use for buttons, pop-up menus and other UI controls.
> - Highlight colour
>
>   Choose the colour to use for highlighting selected text.

So the accent colour is used for the current menu selection, for the outline around focused elements, for the default button in alerts and dialogs, for selected checkboxes and radio buttons, for current menu selection, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can then select whether the highlight colour (the selected text) will use the accent colour or a different one.